# Problem of Inequality using wavy curve

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

I came across a relatively simple problem in one of the reference books whose answer surprised me. It is based on finding the **range of numbers** that can be taken by ***x*** so that the inequality is satisfied.

The question goes on like this:

> *Find the number of integers satisfying the inequality; **(x^2+2)/(x^2-1) < -2***

What I did to find the answer was to being the '-2' to LHS and then simply to get a result:

> ***[(3x^2)/{(x+1)(x-1)}] < 0***

Since for any Real value of ***x*** the numerator will be positive, I took it to the RHS and simplified the inequality further:

> ***[1/{(x+1)(x-1)}] < 0***

Using the method of wavy curve:
[image]

I get the possible *range of values* of *x* as **x ∈ (-1,1)**. Hence the answer to the question asked terns out to be ***"only one integer which here is zero."***.

But here comes the real problem, when ***"zero, 0"*** is substituted inn the place of x in the above inequality the answer turns out to be:

> ***{2/(-1)} < -2***
>
> Hence, ***(-2) < (-2)***

which is clearly not correct. What is the mistake I am doing or is there some other flaws in the method of wavy curve?

Comment: Your error is the assertion that "for any Real value of x the numerator will be positive." In fact, you found exactly the counterexample.

Comment: It is indeed true that for any value of x^2 will be possible right? What is wrong in that?

Comment: $0$ is not positive........

Comment: When you "simplified the inequality further", you divided by 0 in the case where $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator in $$\frac {3x^2}{(x-1)(x+1)}$ is not positive for all real values of x.

It is zero at $x=0$ where you need to pay a special attention.